# What is the best way to get the value of a div?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on a site that has random background images in the container. Every time you load the site there is a different image generated by a php script. 
When the PHP script randomly chooses 1.jpg to show, I would like bg1.png to be used as background image.
If the PHP script randomly chooses 2.jpg to show, I would like bg2.png to be used as background image.

This is the jQuery i already made. But I can not find a way how to call the value of the div called background

The  jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ($("#background").attr("value") == 1) {
$(body).css("background-image", "url(images/bg/bg1.png);");
}

else if ($("#background").attr("value") == 2) {
$(body).css("background-image", "url(images/bg/bg2.png);");
}

else if ($("#background").attr("value") == 3) {
$(body).css("background-image", "url(images/bg/bg3.png);");
}

else if ($("#background").attr("value") == 4) {
$(body).css("background-image", "url(images/bg/bg4.png);");
}

else if ($("#background").attr("value") == 5) {
$(body).css("background-image", "url(images/bg/bg5.png);");
}

else if ($("#background").attr("value") == 6) {
$(body).css("background-image", "url(images/bg/bg6.png);");
}

else {
$(body).css("background-image", "url(images/bg.png);");
}
});
```

The Php:

```
echo "<div id='background' value=\"$random\"><img src=\"$image_folder/$image_name\" alt=\"$random\" /></div>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing now is quite silly, consider setting the background by echo'ing the code in PHP.
For example:

```
<style>
body
{
 background-image: url("images/bg<?php echo rand(0,7); ?>.png");
}
</style>
```

There shouldnt be any clientside processing needed here.

Comment: Agreed. Use javascript when it needs to be used - when client side manipulation is involved.

Comment: Do note that it will always append bg with a number, so make sure bg0.png exists too for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    var mainImage = $("#background").attr("value");
    $("BODY").css("background-image", "url(images/bg/bg" + mainImage + ".png)");
});
```

This could be achieved quite easily just via PHP though - especially as you're already generating the number to be used in the filename.

I'd also suggest using the `rel` attribute on your divs as `value` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using custom properties in your div's. The correct way would be to look at the `src` property in your `img` tag

```
$("#background img").attr("src")
```